# SYSTEM tablespace in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't know how to get all tables from SYSTEM tablespace in oracle database.

I'm executing the next command:

```
select * 
from dba_tables 
where tablespace_name='SYSTEM';
```

However, tables like all_users or ALL_TABLES are not listed in this output (I read these tables are from SYSTEM tablespace here: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sys_tables/index.php).

What am I doing wrong? This is what I understand: SYSTEM is a tablespace which contains metadata about database information, that is why it has some tables like "all_tables".

Please, correct me as much as possible if I am wrong.

Comment: This question demonstrates the problems of relying on unofficial resources on the internet rather than the actual Oracle documentation. Those are  not tables, but **views** in the Oracle data dictionary. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-8865F65B-EF6D-44A5-B0A1-3179EFF0C36A.htm#REFRN002).

Comment: tablespace contains data files. To get the data you should query based on schema.

Answer (score 1):

`Tablespace` in Oracle terms is a physical or in-memory location for data storage. What you are referring to in your question are `schemas`.

For the most part, the data dictionary contains views, not tables. You can find them by querying all_views instead of all_tables. Because they are dynamic views and do not store data, there is no tablespace. Instead, query the schema owners `SYS` and 'SYSTEM`.

```
SELECT *
  FROM all_views
 WHERE owner IN ('SYS', 'SYSTEM')
```

Comment: I would add both 'SYS' and 'SYSTEM': `select * from dba_tables where owner in ('SYS','SYSTEM')`

Answer (score 1):

`ALL_USERS` and `ALL_TABLES` are views, not tables, and as such they appear in the ALL_VIEWS view. The following queries might be useful to you:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ALL_TABLES
  WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME = 'SYSTEM';

SELECT OWNER, VIEW_NAME
  FROM ALL_VIEWS
  WHERE VIEW_NAME IN ('ALL_USERS', 'ALL_TABLES')

SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME
  FROM ALL_TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('ALL_USERS', 'ALL_TABLES')
```

[See this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=32b40c4414bc797963948665a26e9b48)